# difference between node_modules/babel-core and node_modules/@babel/core

Tags: react-native, babeljs

I'm trying to upgrade react-native from 0.51.0 to 0.56.0

I see `node_modules/babel-core` is 6.x and `node_modules/@babel/core` is 7.x .

I think this is causing some problems when bundling.

When I scan my app's package.json there's no @babel (with 7.x)
Why is `@babel` being installed and how can I prevent it so that I can only use 6.x or 7.x ?